# Why Laravel Event Queue Keep Using Old Source That Not Exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

Hi I'm using queue to run a task, in the task there simple function that hit another api to post data,
now I change that code to use kafka and remove the proses to post to api

The problem is, the queue is randomly use old source code(hit the api, and not using kafka), and I don't know why

I'am using

```
php artisan queue:work
```

with database driver queue, on laravel 5.6

I try some tips, just like

```
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan queue:flush
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer dumpautoload -o
```

and reinstall the laravel vendor

but the queue still randomly use old source code,

how can I solve this, so the queue use the latest code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem, so this is because using 2 servers with same queue connection (database), 1 server is using the latest code and another server is using the old code

So the supervisor on the another server with old code must be stopped

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your supervisor use an updated source code you have to restart your supervisor.

```
supervisorctl restart all
```